# Given a dag run id, is it possible to find the dag id using Airflow SDK

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

Given a DAG run id (eg. *scheduled__2021-11-30T09:30:00+00:00*)

Is it possible to find the DAG id and other details of the dag and dag run using Airflow python SDK?